# What is the order item view path?

Tags: commerce

I need to allow admins to print off individual order items (line items) that relate to a specific product, and allow them to print off the order item using Entity Print. the order item has customised data in it that they need to print off.

However, I cannot work out what the path to view the entity is. I tried /commerce_order_item/{id}, /commerce_order_item/bundle/{id} and variations, but to no avail. I know the entity can be rendered, as it has a Manage Display configuration, and I can even render the entity in a view.